# My Toggle Icon Not Functioning well. It shifted from right to left when i do click on it

Tags: html

I have made a responsive navigation bar, but when the screen gets small and I click on the toggle icon to expand it, my toggle icon gets shifted from right to left.
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4aap.png) of the problem.

A link to my code:
https://github.com/Anonsatyam/Responsive-navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you forgot to add "px". [See this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVASV.png)

[image: screenshot of the code around line 60]

Comment: For people who prefer not to click the link and go to line 60, what does the full line say? What is the context? Why is OP having this problem? How does your solution fix it?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience.